# List questions with recently accepted answers?

Tags: feature-request, question-lists

Just a small thing...

I'd like to suggest adding "recently accepted" to the filters available when listing questions, this would list questions with recently accepted answers, in order (newest first) of the date the answer was accepted.

I often find it quite educating scanning down the "questions/active" list and picking out those with accepted answers. While active questions without accepted answers may still have relevant/interesting/useful answers in them, a question with an accepted answers is (almost) guaranteed to have such an answer within the responses. Having a "recently accepted" filter would allow me to be extra lazy and save a couple of "next page" clicks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A search for `hasaccepted:1` sorted by newest doesn't work for you?

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hasaccepted:1&tab=newest

Comment: More or less. Though the way I read that it is sorting by the date of the question, not when the answer was accepted - so a question three weeks old that has just had an answer accepted won't be at the top. `hasaccepted:1`/active seems pretty close to what I was looking for though. Thanks for the `hasaccepted:1` insight.